# make a different countdown after actual countdown

Tags: javascript, html

I need help with the next countdown. I need to reset the actual countdown with a new different date when the actual countdown finishes. All this in one simple counter.

```js
$(function (){

function countdown() {

var now = new Date();
var eventDate = new Date('Nov 03, 2017 13:02:20');
var secondEventDate =  new Date('Nov 09, 2017 10:18:40');
var currentTime = now.getTime();
var evenTime = eventDate.getTime();

if(eventDate<=currentTime){
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "expired";
    clearInterval(setTimeout);

}

var remTime = evenTime - currentTime;

var sec = Math.floor(remTime / 1000);
var min = Math.floor(sec / 60);
var hur = Math.floor(min / 60);
var day = Math.floor(hur / 24);

 hur %= 24;
 min %= 60;
 sec %= 60;

hur = (hur < 10) ? "0" + hur : hur;
min = (min < 10) ? "0" + min : min;
sec = (sec < 10) ? "0" + sec : sec;

$('.seconds').text(sec);
$('.minutes').text(min);
$('.hours').text(hur);
$('.days').text(day);

setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
}

countdown();


});
```

Comment: Some spelling, reworded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets clean up the code a bit. At first we need some helper functions:

```
const addZero = n => n < 10 ? "0" + n : n;
const format = ms => {
   const result = [];
   [1000,60,60,24,31].reduce((carry, max) => {
      result.unshift(carry % max);
      return Math.floor(carry / max);
   },ms);
   result.pop();//remove milliseconds
   return result.map(addZero).join(":");
};
```

So now we need a Timer, like this:

```
class Timer {
  constructor(to, el, finish){
    this.to = to;
    this.el = el;
    this.finish = finish;
    setTimeout(_ => this.update(), 1000);
  }
  update(){
    const ms = this.to - Date.now();
    this.el.innerHTML = format(ms);
    if(ms < 0){
       this.finish();
    }else{
      setTimeout(_ => this.update(), 1000);
    }
  }
}
```

So to setup the timers:

```
new Timer(
   new Date('Nov 03, 2017 13:02:20'),
   document.body,
   () => new Timer(
      new Date('Nov 03, 2017 13:02:20'),
      document.body, 
      _ => _
   )
);
```

[Try it](http://jsbin.com/sijiruqoto/edit?output)